# Help with identifying plant (Pink Stem, Green leaves)

Tags: identification, houseplants, indoors

As can be seen in the image, the plant has a pink stem, pale green leaves, and grows close to the ground.
It is also probably native to the Indian Subcontinent. (I currently live in Southern India.)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are the leaves thick and fleshy? Thinnish and leathery?

Comment: @Jurp They are thin and leathery.

Comment: This doesn't deserve to be an answer because I don't have a definite ID, but the growth habit of your plant looks like it could be a non-colorful species of aglaonema, homalomena, or other member of the Araceae family. Aglaonema tends to be native to the east and south of India while homalomena come from southern Asia, so that fits. There are cultivars of Homalomena with red/pink stems, but their leaves have more noticeable veining &/or different shapes. Other cultivars my match, though. For example, Homolomena 'Lime' matches leaf color and kind of the stem color, but not the veining.

Comment: I just discovered that many Homamolena have a strong smell of anise. This would, IMO, allow for a definitive ID as "Homamolena" if your plant also smells of anise (lack of the smell would not rule out Homamolena, though, but would rule out the ID). Best way to release the scent would be to tear or crush a leaf. Please let me know if the plant does or does not have a scent via a comment.

Comment: @Jurp There is no scent

Comment: While that doesn't rule out a Homamolena cultivar, it also doesn't rule it in, although I'm of the opinion that that ID is incorrect. My guess now is that it's a different member of the Araceae, although most of those plants have arrowhead-shaped leaves.

Answer (score 2):

This is a quite late response but I was looking to ID my plant that looks similar and it seems like it could be baby philodendron Malay gold!

Comment: Please post a photo of it so everyone can see that they are the same plant.

Comment: @RohitGupta I second this answer as being Philodendron Malay gold. These plants are quite popular in Rainy humid tropics as houseplants. I glanced a few at my cousin's house. I'll try to revert with a pic If I find it them again. But I for now, can assure you it's a Malay Golden Goddess Philodendron.

Answer (score 1):

While I don't think I'm correct, how you mention pink stems reminds me of the Fire Flash spider plant (which might be Chlorophytum orchidastrum or Chlorophytum amaniense). They look similar, but a bit different than yours to me.

Answer (score 0):

I just scanned with Picturethis android app, it suggest Marsh seedbox (Primrose willows) or Cylindricfruit primrose willow.

On searching the internet, it seems there are so many different varieties for this plant. May be you can use this to narrow down your search

Comment: Thank you for the answer. For the Marsh Seedbox, the reddish stem is a tick, but the other features seem quite dissimilar, based on the images I found online. The Cylindricfruit Primrose Willow also possesses different features, and is found in the southern states of North America, according to the wikipedia page.

Answer (score -2):

OK I will start the ball rolling with [Pokeweed](https://www.oardc.ohio-state.edu/weedguide/single_weed.php?id=112). Reasons favouring this choice are the red petioles; note that in the Ohio weedguide description that the redness goes up the leaf stem but is visible on the underside only. Leaf is entire (no jaggies) and oval shaped, uncomplicated.

Against this choice (although the images offered are of a very young plant) are that the veining is not as complicated as in the Ohio description, also the leaf stems are clasping the main stem in the offered image, sort of like rhubarb. There is a curious hook on one of the plant petioles which is an unusual place to have a growth.

It should be easy to dismiss this as pokeweed later, if no "large fleshy white taproot" appears. Not sure why pokeweed would be in a pot.

Comment: Sorry Colin, but this isn't pokeweed. It's become quite a pest where I live (from zero plants in my part of the city in 2015 to hundreds of them last summer), so I"m quite familiar with it in all stages of its growth (for example, the leaves in the photo are too narrow and have less noticeable veining than pokeweed of the same size plant).

Comment: Thanks Jurp. I will leave my answer in place just in case someone else falls into the same hole. I'll delete it when a much better possibility is suggested. As long as it stays at 0 votes it won't deprive others of the bounty. What on earth is that little hook thing on that leaf stem?